# Manipular componentes de um container

Tags: java, swing

Adicionei uma `frame` com vários componentes a um `container`. Noutra classe eu adiciono ao jPanel os dados do `container`. Nesta classe, há alguma maneira de eu ter acesso aos componentes desse `container` ?

```
Container ct3 = new Container();
ct3 = this.getContentPane();
```

A questão é que eu adicionei todos os componentes da frame ao `container`, mas quando eu mostro esses componentes noutra classe, gostava que alguns componentes não fossem mostrados.
Na outra classe tenho isso:

```
painelPrincipalConfMainMenu.add(ConfUtilizador.ct3.getComponent(0));
```

Há alguma maneira de fazer isso ?

Comment: Mas e depois como é que disponho os elementos da primeira frame do mesmo modo, mas na nova frame ?

Comment: Pois sugestão errada, vou remover e publicar uma resposta que te pode ajudar

Answer (score 1):

Testa assim:

Código:

```
    Component[] components = ConfUtilizador.ct3.getContentPane().getComponents();

    for (int i = 0; i < components.length; ++i) {
        if ((components[i] instanceof JButton)) {
            System.out.println(" um botao");
            JButton button = components[i];
            if(button.getttext().equals("ok"))
                   button.setVisivel(false);

        }else if ((components[i] instanceof JLabel)){
            System.out.println(" uma label");
            JLabel label= components[i];
            if(label.getttext().equals("nome"))
                   label.setVisivel(false);
        }else {
            System.out.println(" outro componente qualquer");
          }
    }
```

Comment: Mas esse Component[] components, é feito no construtor da primeira frame. E depois como é que eu o percorro na outra classe para os adicionar à nova frame?

Comment: Editei o código, eu suponho que tens acesso a esse container no novo `frame`, onde queres adicionar os `components`

Comment: Será algo desse género? :
for(int i = 0; i < componentes.length ; i++){
             if ((componentes[i] instanceof JButton)) {
            JButton button = (JButton) componentes[i];
            if(button.getText().equals("botaoCancelar"))
                   button.setVisible(false);
                   painelPrincipalConfMainMenu.add(componentes[i]);
        }
        }

Comment: Sim penso que sim, só no ultimo `painelPrincipalConfMainMenu.add(componentes[i]);` podes usar o button que criaste, mas porque? não funciona?

Comment: painelPrincipalConfMainMenu.add(componentes[i]); isso fica sublinhado a amarelo e diz 'Confusing identation'
EDIT: O erro era por outra coisa que já corrigi. Não dá erro nem adiciona nada à frame

Comment: pois usa o botão que criaste tipo assim: `painelPrincipalConfMainMenu.add(button); `

Comment: componentes.length()=1 :S como é que é possível se na frame tenho muitos componentes?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19208/discussion-between-jsantos1991-and-hugo-machado).